# Why is my guildCreate not firing when my guildDelete is?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Joining the server doesn't work, leaving it does. This is driving me nuts. Any thoughts?

```
    //Join server message **console logging nothing**
    client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
        console.log(`Server: Joined \"${guild.name}\"!`);
        guild.author.send(`Yo, use ${prefix}help to get started.`);
    });
    
    //Leave server message **console working**
    client.on('guildDelete', (guild) => {
        console.log(`Server: Left \"${guild.name}\" :(`);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found my own answer, because of how I laid out my code, guildCreate was not running until the first person sent a command to the bot, a simple movement of lines fixed it. God I hate programming

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening due to you not giving bot enough intents. If that's the case, try to give bot intent named "GUILDS".

Comment: I gave the bot all intents so I don't think that's it